# How to highlight a node in D3 via Query String?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a collapsible D3 Tree which I have modified to work with Angular 4. Everything is working fine.

Script reads the Params in the URL, grab the ID in the params and open the graph until the requested node ( attachment )

[image]

URL:
`/asset-graph?id=27`

In this case ID 27 is the Asset 3 in the graph.

I need to change the colour or highlight the requested node in the graph.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
.style('fill', (d: any) => {
      // debugger
      let id;
      if (d._children == null && d.children == null) {
        id = d.data.id;
      }
      if (!UtilService.empty(d.children)) {
        id = d.children[0].data.id;
      }
      if (!UtilService.empty(d._children)) {
        id = d._children[0].data.id;
      }
      if (!UtilService.empty(id)) {
        if ( String(this.parentId) === String(id) ) {
          return 'red';
        } 
      }
      });
```

This code works fine and result is ( attached ) - I selected node 2.2

[image]

**Here is the issue**

Same code is showing the wrong highlighted label if node is a parent: ( attached )

Here I change the params in the URL to Asset 3 but the asset 2 got highlighted.

[image]

Here is the code re-jigged for typescript.

```
...
      ngOnInit() {

        this.svg = this.graphHelper.setUp(
                    this.d3,
                    this.width,
                    this.height,
                    this.margin);

        if ( !UtilService.empty(this.treeData) ) {
          this.root = this.d3.hierarchy(this.treeData, (d: any) => {
            return d.children;
          });
          this.root.x0 = this.height / 2;
          this.root.y0 = 0;
          [this.root].forEach(this.collapse);
          this.update(this.root);
        }

        // this.parentId: Coming from params in URL
        this.find (this.root, this.parentId);
      }

      collapse = (d: any) => {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach((d1) => {d1.parent = d; this.collapse(d1); });
          d._children.forEach(this.collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      find(d, id) {
        if (String(d.data.id) === id) {
          while (d.parent) {
            d = d.parent;
            this.click(d, 'auto'); // if found open its parent
          }
          return;
        }

        // recursively call find function on its children
        if (d.children) {
          d.children.forEach( (da) => { this.find(da, id); });
        } else if (d._children) {
          d._children.forEach( (da) => { this.find(da, id); });
        }
      }

      public update(source) {
        this.treemap = this.d3.tree().size([this.height, this.width]);
        // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
        this.treeData = this.treemap(this.root);

        // Compute the new tree layout.
        const nodes = this.treeData.descendants();
        const links = this.treeData.descendants().slice(1);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach((d) => { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

        // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

        // Update the nodes...
        const node = this.svg.selectAll('g.node')
          .data(nodes, (d: any) => {
            return d.id || ( d.id = ++this.i ); }
          );

        // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
        const nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('transform', (d) => {
            return 'translate(' + source.y0 + ',' + source.x0 + ')';
        })
        .on('click', this.click);

        // Add Circle for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('circle')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('r', 1e-6)
          .style('fill', (d: any) => {
              return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
          });

        // Add labels for the nodes
        nodeEnter.append('a')
        .append('text')
        .attr('dy', '.35em')
        .attr('x', (d: any) => {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
        })
        .attr('text-anchor', (d: any) => {
          return d.children || d._children ? 'end' : 'start';
        })
        .text( (d: any) => {
          return `${d.data.asset_name.length > LIMIT_LENGTH ? d.data.asset_name.substr(0, LIMIT_LENGTH) + '...' : d.data.asset_name}`;
        });

        // UPDATE
        const nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        // Transition to the proper position for the node
        nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(this.duration)
        .attr('transform', (d) => {
            return 'translate(' + d.y + ',' + d.x + ')';
        });

        // Update the node attributes and style
        nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 4.5)
        .style('fill', (d: any) => {
            return d._children ? 'lightsteelblue' : '#fff';
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

        // Remove any exiting nodes
        const nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(this.duration)
          .attr('transform', (d) => {
              return 'translate(' + source.y + ',' + source.x + ')';
          })
          .remove();

        // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
        nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

        // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
        nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

        // ****************** links section ***************************

        // Update the links...
        const link = this.svg.selectAll('path.link')
          .data(links, (d: any) => {
            return d.id;
          });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        const linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', 'g')
          .attr('class', 'link')
          .attr('d', (d: any) => {
            const o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return this.diagonal(o, o);
          });

        // UPDATE
        const linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

        // Transition back to the parent element position
        linkUpdate.transition()
          .duration(this.duration)
          .attr('d', (d: any) => {
            return this.diagonal(d, d.parent);
          });

        // Remove any exiting links
        const linkExit = link.exit().transition()
          .duration(this.duration)
          .attr('d', (d: any) => {
            const o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return this.diagonal(o, o);
          })
          .remove();

        // Store the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach((d: any) => {
          d.x0 = d.x;
          d.y0 = d.y;
        });
      }

      diagonal(s, d) {
        const path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
                C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
                  ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
                  ${d.y} ${d.x}`;
        return path;
      }

      click = (d, type) => {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
          } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
          }
        this.update(d);
        this.clickMe(d.data.id, type);
      }

      clickMe = (d, type?) => {
        if (type !== 'auto') {
          this.graphSrv.callServer(d);
          this.updateLoader = true;
        }
        this.callback = d;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code in Code snippet or somewhere else so that we can see it

Comment: hmmm, I have. It is in the question. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Or do you want me to make a CodePen or JSBin from it?

Comment: Yes if you can share it in CodePen that would be useful to test it